# How can I multiply each row by a number depending on the values of the row?

Tags: pandas

I have this DF and I'm looking to multiply the the number of rows depending in the amount of words col3 has. Is this something that can be done in Python?

```
col1    col2    col3
A1      B1      a - ab - abc
A13     B13     a - ab
A27     B27     abcd
```

desired output

```
col1    col2    col3
A1      B1      a - ab - abc
A1      B1      a - ab - abc
A1      B1      a - ab - abc
A13     B13     a - ab
A13     B13     a - ab
A27     B27     abcd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for counting words and then repeat rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['col3'].str.count('\w+'))].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  col1 col2          col3
0   A1   B1  a - ab - abc
1   A1   B1  a - ab - abc
2   A1   B1  a - ab - abc
3  A13  B13        a - ab
4  A13  B13        a - ab
5  A27  B27          abcd
```

If there are always separated words by `-` is possible count it and add `1`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['col3'].str.count('-') + 1)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or solution by @sammywemmy, thank you with splitting and length of lists:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.col3.str.split('-').str.len())].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: ```df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.col3.str.split('-').str.len())]```